# Javascript: [Array(2),Array(2)] versus [["a","b"],["c","d"]] - What is the difference and why are they not equal?

Tags: javascript, methods

In JavaScript, I'm working on this problem from FreeCodeCamp to which my result is an array of Array objects instead of an array of arrays.

My function:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
      let finArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + size){
        let subArr = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < size; j++){
          if (!!arr[i+j] == true || arr[i+j] == 0){
            subArr.push(arr[i+j]);
          }
        }
        finArr.push(subArr);
      }
      return finArr;
    }
```

This function will separate the input `array` into chunks of `size`. However, when calling `chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);` my result in Javascript terminal (Google Chrome) is :

```
(2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ["a", "b"]
1: (2) ["c", "d"]
```

Which according to the the Google terminal DOES NOT equal `[["a","b"],["c","d"]]`, which is the right solution. What is the difference between this last notation and the notation I receive as output from my function? I'm utterly confused by the differences between these.

---

EDIT: as pointed out by @ASDFGerte, they don't equal when using ==. What would be the reasoning behind this?

Also, my code didn't contain a case for `!!arr[i+j]` being `false`, which I added an OR case for as `if (!!arr[i+j] || arr[i+j] == 0)`

Comment: You're letting the console conventions confuse you. Your code works correctly.

Comment: Can you elaborate "does not equal"? I am making sure, that you don't just try `[["a","b"],["c","d"]] === [["a","b"],["c","d"]]`, which would always be `false`.

Comment: Also `if (!!arr[i+j] == true)` does exactly the same thing as the simpler `if (arr[i+j])`

Comment: It does "equal".

Comment: `my result is an array of Array objects instead of an array of arrays`. In JavaScript arrays are Array objects

Comment: Your code returns the expected result. `[Array(2), Array(2)]` is just how the chrome console displays nested arrays or objects. You can use `JSON.stringify( chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2) )` to get `[["a","b"],["c","d"]]` in a single line

Comment: @ASDFGerte you seem to be correct. This is the evaluation I am doing but they aren't equal. Why would it always be `false`?